# Is there a way to exclude other particle systems from the effects of a Wind effect?

Tags: particles

I have a scene with a number of particle systems. I'd like to have a separate wind effect for my main scene and another for an extra: an emitter + wind-effect to blow leaves into my scene.

I can't find any way to exclude, so here I am.

At the very worst, I can just render the main scene and then render the wind effect and composite it, but I figured I'd check first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make a wind only for a particle system and another wind for a second particle system, you need to put the particles and the Winds inside different Collections and then, go to each Particle System > Field Weights > Effector Collection

In the collection box add the collection of each particle system to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Goodness, a particle problem that was solvable. Many thanks to you.

Comment: no problem, man!

Answer (score 0):

In the particles settings, under Field Weights, there is an option which allows you to decide how much effect different forces have on the particle system. You can set wind to 0 for no influence, or 1 for a full effect.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking to have particle systems that are excluded entirely from wind or if you are asking to have particle systems effected by different wind force fields