# Particles start flying away in random directions when adding particle system with duplicate setting

Tags: particles, looping

I try to make looping animation of falling particles.

I created particle system on a plane with the following settings:

Physics:

- Type: `Newtonia`
- Brownian: `9.03`
- Drag: `0.318`
- Damp: `0.103`

Force fields:

- Type: `Turbulence`
- Strength: `15.0`

First particle system starts at frame `-50` and ends at frame `50`, second - at frame `50` and ends at `150`.

When I have a single particle system particles fall down as expected.
If I add a duplicate of the first particle system - and even if I add a completely new particle system and type its settings by hand - particles start misbehaving at frame `51` onwards - they start flying in random directions instead of falling down - i.e. animation changes to a some sort of explosion instead of falling down.

Perhaps force field settings need to be tweaked somehow to prevent this effect and make particle systems to "blend" seamlessly?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198835/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-other-particle-systems-from-the-effects-of-a-wind-effe/198839#198839

Comment: It doesn't seem so - the effect still exists when the first particle system gets disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Force Field** settings you are **Turbulence** with each particle as effector and strength of **15**.

That is too much to keep the system stable if each particle acts as an effector.

Instead chose a few particles among the whole set to act as effectors. You can set the **Effector Amount to 10**. Also you can enable **Self Effect** to affect the particles of their own particle system. Do the same for both particle systems.

Also sometimes the Cache is buggy and you have to reset it by changing a value for example the **Seed**. To run the simulation correctly I've found that moving the playhead to the initial frame in this case -50 helps. To do this **Allow Negative Frames** in your **Preferences** so you can move the playhead on a negative frame (note your animation still starts at 0)

[image]

Here is a blend file that will work with the described settings above

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I found another possible solution which is to empty effector collection. Yours indeed is cleaner.

Comment: You're welcome.